# Can not activate navigator.storage.persist in Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, offline-storage

StorageManager has an API to make offline storages persistent which make them not to suffer from purging when there is not enough free space on user's drive.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/persist

I want to use persistant offline storage for my website.
Persistant mode can be activated using this code:

```
navigator.storage.persist.then(
  function(persist_enabled) {console.log(persist_enabled)}
)
```

When this command is executed in Desktop FireFox version the browser prompts a permission and if a user allowed it persist_enabled is "true".

But when I run this command in Android Firefox version there is no permission prompt and the result is always "false".

Is there some condition I must to satisfy to turn this feature on on Adroid Firefox?

**Update 2020.09.29**

Firefox support team said that it is a bug. The permission prompt must be popped up but it's not. We should wait for a fix.
https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/issues/3153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bad news for current date (checked on `9'th september 2020`)

According to "Can i use" site (https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_storagemanager) this feature is not supported by default in `Firefox 79 for Android`. It must be enabled via internal configuration.

So it's not possible to use this feature for a regular site for now as users probably would not enable it.

Upd. 2020.12.11
There was a bug in Firefox for Android. The prompt should popup but it's not.
Here is a related issue in github: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/14875
The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with chrome, and I solved this by bookmarking the application...
Accordingly with [this](https://web.dev/persistent-storage/) documentation the browsers follow some heuristics to prompt this popup, and sometimes they may silently deny the permission.

Comment: Yes in Chrome that works fine. But I need this feature in Firefox for Android

Comment: This [site](https://storage-quota.glitch.me/) helped me to debug my application, maybe it can help you too. You can look at the console with the messages and see the source code too